# Ajax post method not working shows status code 400

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My ajax code for is not working. it shows error

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxx.xxx.xxx No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.`

How to solve the problem. I have tried the different headers. But not posting the data. Please to solve my issue.
my code is

```
$http({
       method: "post",
       dataType:'json',
        url: res,
       crossDomain : true,
        data: {
            'name': $scope.name,
            'email': $scope.email,
             'text area': $scope.query

        },
headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }
    }).then(function success(data) {


        alert("Message sent succesfully");
        /*var success=data.data.issuccess;
        if(success==true)
        {
          var name=data.data.username;
          var userid=data.data.userid;
          alert("Name= "+name+ "UserId="+userid);
        }*/




    });
```

It's working postman as correct. but not in ajax. [image]

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, you need to enable CORS _on that server_.  Learn how CORS works.

Comment: If javascript alone could circumvent CORS, it wouldn't be much of a security feature.

Comment: you have to enable  cross origin  request i.e `CORS` in your server.

Comment: you server is blocking the request which are from other domains

Comment: @SLaks I have enable cors by crossDomain : true.

Comment: @Joe: You need to enable CORS _on the server_.  Learn what CORS actually does.

Comment: @Taplar How to post data using ajax. pls help me.

Comment: @Joe: You need to learn about the Same-Origin Policy.

Comment: @GhanshyamSingh I have use crossOrgin:true. bur problem not solved.

Comment: @SLaks Is it possible to post data.

Comment: That's completely possible, but you need to read and understand https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS.

Comment: @SLaks i am using mobile app development. I didn't understand what to do.

Comment: _You need to read the article and configure your server_.  If you refuse to learn anything, we can't help you.

Comment: This is not something you can do in your own code. As @SLaks has said, you must enable CORS access on the server. Do you have access to the server that is hosting the application you're sending the AJAX request to? Because if not, you will not be able to fix this. The browser is blocking the request because your AJAX request is not coming from the same server the web application came from. It works in Postman because that doesn't use the browser rules. As SLaks has said, read up on how to work with CORS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solve the problem. It is the problem face in server side. and i change the code is

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://xxx.xx.xx.xx/api/SendMail/SendEmail",
type: "POST",
async: false,
ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
data:  {
            'subject': "Contact us from SQU app",
            'message': msgSQU

        },
crossOrigin: true,
dataType: "json",
success: function (response) {
$resData = response;
//alert("Su");
showConfirm("Your Feedback succesfully send");


},
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
alert('error');
//console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
}
});
```

Now it is working as fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable CORS on the server.

Please read this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Also check this one:

https://enable-cors.org/server.html

Note:  I am correcting this after reading the comment from SLaks. He is correct.

Comment: I am testing in remote server.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `http://xxx.xxx.xxx` doesn't send the right header in its response for you to be able to access it. See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-examples for flow examples.

Comment: I cannot find out the answer. please help me.